# Javascript cannot access Java Applet Public Method besides AWT?

Tags: java, javascript, swing, security, applet

I'm just working with some tasks. One of them, required me to use javascript to access Java Applet public methods. As I tried so far, I can only access to method that use awt. Otherwise, it did not let me see something happened. Is my thought wrong? What's is the matter on here?

1/ Here is my simple applet code:

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

public class MyApplet extends Applet{

    public void setBackColor(){
        setBackground(Color.cyan);
    }

    public void writeFile(){
        try {
            String content = "This is the content to write into file";
            File file = new File("filename.txt");
            if (!file.exists()) {
               file.createNewFile();
            }

            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
            BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
            bw.write(content);
            bw.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

2/ Sample Html:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script language="javascript">
        function setBackground(){document.app.setBackColor();}
        function WritetoFile(){document.app.writeFile();}
    </script>
</head>
<applet code="MyApplet" name="app" width="300" height="200"></applet>
<button onclick="setBackground()">Set Background Color</button>
<button onclick="WritetoFile()">Write Data To File</button>
</html>
```

I need to access both of the methods in the class, but cannot. The code only working with `setBackColor()` method, but another one,`writeFile()`, did not work.

*Any ideas or suit solution? Please help...*

Comment: I am not sure, though might be Security Issues, associated with accessing a file on the File System. Have you tried, setting the security settings to Minimum(to Medium I mean)?

Comment: Yes, I already did that with `javacpl.exe` file. Since before, If I did not set Minimum, even `setBackground()` also did not work.

Comment: After setting, only `setBackground()` worked.

Comment: Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.  Note that when called by JS, the 'trusted method' needs to be invoked from one of the [`AccessController.doPrivileged(..)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/AccessController.html#method.summary) methods.  (And of course, the applet will need to be digitally signed using a valid code signing certificate, and specify `all-permissions` in the manifest, to write to a `File`.)